# Using this operation -> inside and outside class

Tags: php, function, accessor

I know how this operation works (->) but I'm just curious. As you can see from the following code when you use it inside a class it's like this `$this->$name` but outside a class it's like `$a->attribute`. So why the first one you use two dollar signs ($) but the second one you use only one dollar sign? I'm so curious. I can just ignore it but it's getting on my nerves.

```
<?php
    class classname
    {
        public $attribute;
        public function __get($name)
        {
            return $this->$name;
        }
    }
    $a = new classname();
    $a->attribute = "Hello";
    echo $a->attribute;
?>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Because inside the magic `__get()` method, the value of `$name` is ___dynamic___

Comment: `$this->$name` is actually a form of a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to dynamically access an object property.  If the input `$name` is `'foo'`, it results in `$this->foo` or `'bar'` to `$this->bar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this -> $name` where `$this` contains the class of the object, `$name` you are already passed value to it, so you declared like `$this->$name`.

`$a->attribute` which is already declared so you are accessing object with property.

If you use the uninitialized property you can directly use `$this->name`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it now ^_^